# Upgrading Rails 2.3.2 to Rails 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I've been given the responsibility of a fairly large legacy Rails 2.3.2 app and I've been asked to add a reasonably complex RESTful API to this app that outputs data in JSON.

After doing my research, I've come to the conclusion that using the RABL gem is probably the best plan given the nature of the API calls. However, I see that the dependencies of RABL require ActiveSupport 2.3.14.

Now, I assume that I can't have both ActiveSupport 2.3.2 and ActiveSupport 2.3.14 both working in the same app and, if I understand correctly, if I upgrade ActiveSupport then I will need to upgrade the rest of the Rails packages as well due to the dependency requirements.

Can anyone tell me the differences between Rails 2.3.2 and Rails 2.3.14 or where I might find that information so that I have some understanding of whether or not I'm likely to break some of the existing functionality?

Alternatively, if there are some serious differences between the two versions of Rails, can anyone recommend an alternative to RABL? I've looked at quite a few of the others such as Jsonify, JBuilder, Tequila, etc. but RABL really appeals in that it constructs the response via views rather than in the controller like some of the others.

Comment: Step 1 is to drop in Rails 2.3.14 and run your test suite. See what, if anything, breaks.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I would if I could.

Lets just say that the previous developers who worked on this legacy app didn't like the "overhead" of updating test cases. One of my biggest hassles with this system is the complete lack of tests :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I couldn't use the RABL gem, or any of the others for that matter.

The differences between the two versions of ActiveSupport caused the app to break in the I18n methods.

I'm not 100% sure if this is an inbuilt difference that applies to all apps or if this is something peculiar to this legacy app as the original developers have done some very unconventional things in building the app and, I suspect, have hacked the base Rails code in a few places.

However, I did end up generating the JSON I needed using the json and json_pure gems which quite simply allow you to generate JSON from a hash. They work quite well and do not need many of the dependencies that a lot of the other gems required.

It does mean that you have to assemble the hash inside the controller which is less than ideal to my way of thinking since it should be just another view.